# How to create custom megamenu in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

In Shopify navigation, there is no option to add images or categories with images so how to create a mega menu with all those features?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I want to add mega menu where there will be category list and category list with image and simple image and I want to make it using custom coding.

Answer (score 0):

**If the theme you are using provides the megamenu** option you will find it in the customizer

To **customize theme** go to `Online Shop > Themes > Customize`

**If your theme doesn't provide a megamenu** you either:

1. Pick a theme that supports the mentioned features
2. Implement those features in the current theme (edit code) (beware stack overflow is for coding related questions, so just for questions about this)
3. Add a speicific app that will do that

To **edit code** go to `Online Shop > Themes > Actions > Edit code`

Comment: It's a Dawn theme and I am manually customizing it.